# Sharing Windows Phone Runtime Component

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I have implemented functionality as a Windows Phone Runtime Component (C++) project. At the moment this project is part of a Windows Phone 8 Visual Studio solution.

Is it possible to export/convert a Windows Phone Runtime Component into a library which can be easily referenced by other Windows Phone 8 projects, and how? I mean something like the library+header concept from C/C++.

Or is the only solution to create a C++ library which is then referenced by Windows Runtime Components created for each solution individually?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are compiling the project as a WPRTC(C++) then it should output as a {project_name}.winmd

You can use the .winmd file as a dll reference (that's effectively what it is... only with metadata attached).

This should be usable in exactly the same way as the project (although you will get the object browser for header information instead of actual source code).

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I am using (and I accidently forgot to post my solution here when I found out).

Comment: Hi there. I did the same trick as you (reference .winmd) file, but when I try to deploy the WP application, I have an "invalid assembly" problem. Did you encounter this error ? Thanks